# How to search for directory containing file

Tags: bash, find, command, fzf, fd

I just discovered `fzf` (fuzzy finder) and now want to achieve the following using `fd` (https://github.com/sharkdp/fd): From the current directory find immediate parent directories of all files that match the string I typed **as well as** find directories whose name match the string I typed.

I tried doing `cd "$(fd | fzf)"` but the problem which occurs here is that for matching files `fd | fzf` will obviously output the full path to the file and not just to the parent directory meaning `cd` fails on this output. Is there a way of rectifying this without having to define separate commands for each of the above listed conditions?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want, but would something like `T="$(fd | fzf)" ; if [[ -f "$T" ]] ; then T="$(dirname "$T")" ; fi ; cd "$T"` suffice? I.e., if you pick a directory, cd into it; if you pick a file, cd into its directory?

Comment: @frabjous thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[fzf](/questions/tagged/fzf) **has no option** to report only the dirnames of the located files.

You might want to approach the fzf developers to discuss whether such an option would fall within the **scope of their vision** for its functionality.  As for **dirname**, it performs the limited functionality it does in line with Unix's early tradition for many narrowly-focused and independant utilities.

At this time, an approach such as that proposed by *frapjous* is your only alternative.